# How we can create treeView using Angular JS from Single table in Database in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

This is my table structure:

[image: Table structure]

I want create TREEVIEW Format of State---> district --> city --> village in MVC

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[countrylist] 
( 
    [countrylistid]      [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
    [kodepos_postcode]   [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    [kelurahan_village]  [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    [kecamatan_district] [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    [jenis_type]         [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    [kab_city]           [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    [propinsi_state]     [VARCHAR](50) NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_countryList] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [countrylistid] ASC ) 
    WITH (pad_index = OFF, statistics_norecompute = OFF, ignore_dup_key = OFF, 
    allow_row_locks = on, allow_page_locks = on) ON [PRIMARY] 
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Generally Stackoverflow does not answer overly broad 'how do I do this' type questions. In this case it appears you have done little research on your own to develop a treeview or find a package to make a treeview. Additionally, the formatting on your question could be improved for readability. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Below steps you need to perform,

1. Get your data from DB
2. Prepare tree structure in javascript and store that in to scope variable
3. Bind that variable to UI

Once we got proper tree structured data, we can render that using recursive template.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EE6AHdNbmY4QCaLQtcKB?p=preview)**

I considered your data like

**DATA**

```
scope.dataFromDB= [
              {'id':1 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 0, 'village':"State 1"},
              {'id':4 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 2 ,'village':"Taluka 1.1"},
              {'id':3 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 1, 'village':"District 2"},
              {'id':5 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 0, 'village':"State 2"},
              {'id':6 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 0, 'village':"State 3"},
              {'id':2 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 1, 'village':"District 1"},
              {'id':7 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 4, 'village':"village 1.1.1"},
              {'id':8 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 1, 'village':"District 3"},
              {'id':9 ,'propinsi_STATE' : 3, 'village':"Taluka 2.1"}
              ];
```

**HTML**

```
<div my-directive></div>
    <script id="myDirectiveTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
              {{item.village}}
              <div ng-if="item.children.length > 0" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </script>
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTemplate">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.children">
          {{item.village}}
         <div ng-if="item.children.length > 0" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
```

I hope this will help you.